# How to fix Beamer missing number, treated as zero error in matrix (line 63 at the bottom)

Tags: beamer, matrices

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\author{Goos Aaron}
\title{\LaTeX : Opdracht 2}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
%\logo{} 
%\institute{} 
%\date{} 
%\subject{} 
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{frame}{Goniometrische Getallen}
    \[
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        & 0 & \frac{\pi}{6} & \frac{\pi}{4} & \frac{\pi}{3} & \frac{\pi}{2} \\
        \hline
        \sin(x) & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 1 \\
        \hline
        \cos(x) & 1 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
        \hline
    
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{frame}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{default}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{6cm}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figuren/afbPierre.jpg}
        \pause
            
        \column{6cm}
            Na de Fieldsmedaille wint de
Belgische Wiskundige Pierre Deligne in 2013 ook de prestigieuze Abelprijs.  
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
Een matrix van de onderstaande vorm noemen we een Vandermondematrix.

\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & a_{1} & {a_{1}}^2 & \cdots & {a_{1}}^n \\
        1 & a_{2} & {a_{2}}^2 & \cdots & {a_{2}}^n \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        1 & a_{n} & {a_{n}}^2 & \cdots & {a_{n}}^n
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{default}` is wrong as "default" is not a number.

Comment: Use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}` instead of `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{default}`. The value is the expand factor.

Answer (score 6):

As I mentioned in the [comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624180/how-to-fix-beamer-missing-number-treated-as-zero-error-in-matrix-line-63-at-th#comment1558205_624180),

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{default}
```

is wrong as "default" is not a number. In order to restore the original value that it had before you redefined it, you could either look it up or simply use

```
\let\defaultarraystretch\arraystretch
```

before

```
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
```

and then

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{\defaultarraystretch}
```

This is the complete code (with your graphics file replaced by a generic one).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\author{Goos Aaron}
\title{\LaTeX : Opdracht 2}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
%\logo{} 
%\institute{} 
%\date{} 
%\subject{} 
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\let\defaultarraystretch\arraystretch
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{frame}{Goniometrische Getallen}
    \[
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        & 0 & \frac{\pi}{6} & \frac{\pi}{4} & \frac{\pi}{3} & \frac{\pi}{2} \\
        \hline
        \sin(x) & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 1 \\
        \hline
        \cos(x) & 1 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
        \hline
    
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{frame}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{\defaultarraystretch}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{6cm}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
        \pause
            
        \column{6cm}
            Na de Fieldsmedaille wint de
Belgische Wiskundige Pierre Deligne in 2013 ook de prestigieuze Abelprijs.  
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
Een matrix van de onderstaande vorm noemen we een Vandermondematrix.

\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & a_{1} & {a_{1}}^2 & \cdots & {a_{1}}^n \\
        1 & a_{2} & {a_{2}}^2 & \cdots & {a_{2}}^n \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        1 & a_{n} & {a_{n}}^2 & \cdots & {a_{n}}^n
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider the following excerpt from your code:

```
...
\end{frame}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{frame}{Goniometrische Getallen}
    \[
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    ...
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{frame}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{default}
\begin{frame}
...
```

In an immediate sense, the culprit is the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{default}
```

The problem is that the value of `\arraystretch` must be either a positive number or something that evaluates to a positive number. I'm pretty sure that what you *meant* to write is

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
```

---

In a deeper sense, though, the real problem is that you placed the instruction `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` *between* `frame` environments, in effect making its scope extend to the `\end{document}` instruction and necessitating the subsequent attempt to "undo" the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` instruction. Had you placed the instruction `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` *after* instead of before `\begin{frame}`, its scope would have been limited to that `frame` only. Hence, an even better "fix" would be to write

```
...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Goniometrische Getallen}
%%% the scope of the next instruction ends at '\end{frame}'
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} 
    \[
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    ...
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{frame} % end of scope of '\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}'
\begin{frame}
...
```